# Passing a Variable in DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot

I'm trying to pass a variable through to a DATEADD function using PowerBI Desktop DAX so that it changes the Interval.

I'm using

```
Sales Comparison = CALCULATE( [SALES], DATEADD('CALENDAR'[DATE],-1,YEAR))
```

to show sales in the same period last year, but i'd like the YEAR function to be variable.

The idea is to change it so the user can compare to last month, last quarter, etc.

I've created a Period table with month, quarter, year and I've tried to pass it through to show

```
        Sales Comparison = 
        CALCULATE( [SALES],
 DATEADD('CALENDAR'[DATE],-1,VALUES(PERIOD[PERIOD])
        )
    )
```

It errors out showing "the Last Argument must be one of these keywords: DAY, MONTH, QUARTER or YEAR.

I've been replacing the VALUES with SELECTEDVALUE and VALUE; all of which fail on me.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX can be a really frustrating language - so new and raw and yet so restrictive ...

I would duplicate the DATEADD 4 times (for DAY, MONTH, QUARTER and YEAR) and wrap the whole steaming mess in a SWITCH function.  Something like:

```
Sales Comparison =
SWITCH (
    VALUES ( PERIOD[PERIOD] ),
    "DAY", CALCULATE ( [SALES], DATEADD ( 'CALENDAR'[DATE], -1, DAY ) ),
    "MONTH", CALCULATE ( [SALES], DATEADD ( 'CALENDAR'[DATE], -1, MONTH ) ),
    "QUARTER ", CALCULATE ( [SALES], DATEADD ( 'CALENDAR'[DATE], -1, QUARTER ) ),
    "YEAR", CALCULATE ( [SALES], DATEADD ( 'CALENDAR'[DATE], -1, YEAR ) )
)
```

Then I would need a shower.

Comment: Thanks Mike; that'll work but she's not pretty! think i need that shower now too.